# No server response for jtable listAction

Tags: jquery, node.js, jtable, jquery-jtable

I am using jtable for displaying table records in HTML page. My code as follows. In `actions:`, for `listAction`, what can I give for loading data. Am using nodejs server.

In client Side:

```
$('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({  
          title: 'Table of people',  
        actions: {  
            listAction: '/api/users/all'  
        },  
        fields: {  
            user_id: {  
                key: true,  
                list: false  
            },   
            user_name: {  
                title: 'User Name',  
                width: '40%'  
            },  
            user_password: {  
                title: 'Password',  
                width: '20%'  
            }  
        }   
   });  
$('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
```

In Server side:

```
app.get('/api/users/all',getAllUsers);

function getAllUsers(req, res)
{
    userdbConnection.query("SELECT user_id,user_name,user_password FROM user where user.user_name ='aaa' AND user_password='aaa'", function(err, rows, fields)
    {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        if (rows.length > 0)
        {
            var data = JSON.stringify({ Result : "OK", Records : rows[0]});
            res.send(data);
        }
        else
        {
            res.send('NO_DATA_FOUND');
        }
    });
};
```

If I put `listAction: '/api/users/all'`

There is no response form server. Please can anyone help me to resolve.

Comment: Is this URL correct ? `'/api/users/all`

Answer (score 0):

Use it in post instead get:

```js
app.post('/api/users/all',getAllUsers);
```

Comment: Can you explain that code so that others can learn from it instead of just copying and pasting it? Also, isn't that what the OP is already doing or how is it different?

Comment: Sorry, OP needs do like this: app.post('/api/users/all',getAllUsers);